# как привязать бота на rasa к telegram

Tags: python

есть для этого официальная документация: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/telegram/
она говорит про раса х
я скачал раса х и у меня появляться ошибка:

```
Sorry, something went wrong (see error above). Make sure to start Rasa X with valid data and valid domain and config files. Please, also check any warnings that popped up.
If you need help fixing the issue visit our forum: https://forum.rasa.com/.
```

вот весь список:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table conversation_channel_statistic already exists

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py", line 496, in run_locally
    local.main(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\local.py", line 196, in main
    sql_migrations.run_migrations(session)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\sql_migrations.py", line 35, in run_migrations
    _run_schema_migrations(session)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\sql_migrations.py", line 52, in _run_schema_migrations
    _run_alembic_migration(alembic_config)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\sql_migrations.py", line 76, in _run_alembic_migration
    command.upgrade(alembic_config, target_revision)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 298, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\database\schema_migrations\alembic\env.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\database\schema_migrations\alembic\env.py", line 86, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 522, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\database\schema_migrations\alembic\versions\migration_2021_08_13_statistic_on_used_channel_names_017cb274256f.py", line 71, in upgrade
    op.create_table(
  File "<string>", line 8, in create_table
  File "<string>", line 3, in create_table
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\ops.py", line 1252, in create_table
    return operations.invoke(op)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\base.py", line 373, in invoke
    return fn(self, operation)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\operations\toimpl.py", line 101, in create_table
    operations.impl.create_table(table)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 259, in create_table
    self._exec(schema.CreateTable(table))
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\alembic\ddl\impl.py", line 141, in _exec
    return conn.execute(construct, *multiparams, **params)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1289, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 80, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1381, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1845, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2026, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1802, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "c:\users\vai-w\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table conversation_channel_statistic already exists
[SQL:
CREATE TABLE conversation_channel_statistic (
        project_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        channel VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        count INTEGER,
        PRIMARY KEY (project_id, channel),
        FOREIGN KEY(project_id) REFERENCES conversation_statistic (project_id)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

в итоге команда ngrok http 5002 не работает и выводит, что:

```
"ngrok" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

и в итоге я не могу найти вебхуки и привязать бота к телеграму
что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Все заключалось в том, что нужно было скачать ngrok